# Terraform order of ip filter rules for IoT Hub

Tags: azure, ip, terraform, iot, azure-iot-hub

I want to deploy multiple azure cloud resources with terraform. My problem is with the terraform script for an azure IoT Hub, exspecially the ip restriction rules. According to the documentation I can do something like this

```
 resource "azurerm_iothub" "iothubname" {
  name                = "somename"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.someresourcegroup
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.somelocation

  sku {
    name     = "B2"
    capacity = "2"
  }

  fallback_route {
    enabled = true
  }



ip_filter_rule {
    action = "Accept"
    ip_mask ="some_ip_range_1"
    name = "some_name_1"
}



 ip_filter_rule {
      action = "Accept"
        ip_mask ="some_ip_range_2"
        name = "some_name_2"   }



ip_filter_rule {
      action = "Accept"
        ip_mask ="some_ip_range_3"
        name = "some_name_3"
  }



 ip_filter_rule {
      action = "Reject"
        ip_mask ="0.0.0.0/0"
        name = "everything_else"
  }
```

}

Everything works fine, ecept that the ordering of the ip rules is not the same as above and in my case I definitely want the last rule to be the the one with the lowest priority on azure. Azure IoT hub applies the filter rules in order.

How can I enforce a certain ordering of ip filter?

Comment: What order do you get?

Comment: the "everything_else" rule is the 2. rule 1 and 2 are 3. and 4. I can't really see any logic there. I tried changing the order in the terraform script, but the result didn't change.

Comment: Can you change name `everything_else` to `some_name_4` and check?

Comment: i already tried to change the names, hoping that terrafrom/azure will sort them alphanumerically. did not work either.

Comment: Each time do you have the same order? When you delete and create again resource do you have the same order?

Comment: yes this seems to be the case. I guess the order in the terraform script does not matter at all

Comment: Sorry I don't get it, so just to be sure. You have wrong order, but this order is not consistent and may change from deployment to deployment, right?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. The order i see in Azure Portal does not change, no matter how i reorder the terraform script. The "everythin_else" rule is always the second one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227581/discussion-between-krzysztof-madej-and-user7454972).

Comment: Did you try to create ip_filter_rule with for_each cycle?

Comment: Can you share full terraform code of IoT hub?

Comment: the full terrafrom code is quite long, but edited the question with the IoT hub part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use dynamic blocks

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html

**File main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_iothub" "iothubname" {
  name                = "somename"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.someresourcegroup
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.somelocation

  sku {
    name     = "B2"
    capacity = "2"
  }

  fallback_route {
    enabled = true
  }

  dynamic "ip_filter_rule" {
  for_each = var.ip_filter_rule_list
    content {
      action = ip_filter_rule.value.action
      ip_mask = ip_filter_rule.value.ip_mask
      name = ip_filter_rule.value.name
    }
  }
}
```

**File variables.tf**

```
variable "ip_filter_rule_list" {
type = list
default = []
}
```

**Update**

Bug is fixed in terraform provider azurerm v2.57.0

https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/11390

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I tried dynamic blocks but the result is the same. For the time being I will use an azure cli script as a workaround.

Comment: I opened a GitHub issue
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/10341

Comment: seems like noone else has the same problem? the issue still exists..

Comment: it will be fixed soon
https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/pull/11390

Comment: PR is merged and fix will be released in version v2.57.0